# Conditional formatting on all duplicates

Tags: formula, business-objects

I'm trying to make a formatting rule in Business Intelligence/Web Intelligence that changes background color of all duplicates based on one field (address id). The best I've got so far is this:

```
=Previous([Address Id])=[Address Id]
```

But that code only changes the background color on the following duplicate only, not the duplicate before it.

Example:

```
Addr.Id   Name
123       John
234       Henry [not marked]
234       Harold [marked]
345       Lucas
```

I want to change the background color of both of the rows with Addr.Id=234.
My Google Fu hasn't come up with any info on how to compare the self-value with the next value. I only found information about "Relative Value" but this require slicing by dimension (which doesn't work for me).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the duplicate IDs indicated then the simplest way may be to select the `Addr.Id` column and apply the built in Duplicate Values... This will include other `234` if present elsewhere in the list.

If you want the cells with `Henry` and `Harold` indicated then, assuming these are in B3 and B4, select ColumnB other than B1 and apply the rule:

```
=OR(A2=A1,A2=A3)
```

This will not include a name name associated with another `234` in the list (unless that `234` is also immediately above or below a `234`).

Comment: Thanks I will test this and report back.

Comment: Just checking, are you talking about Excel? Cell-references like you are talking about does not work in Business Intelligence as far as I can see.

Comment: if you mean that SAP is making the Web Intelligence/Business Intelligence solution I'm using, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve the above requirement using the following functions `Count()`, `Foreach()` and `Forall()` and conditional formatting

Considering above example:

```
Obj 1: Count(Name)Foreach(Addr.ID)
Obj 2: If obj 1 <> 1 then 1 else 0
Conditional formatting Rule: obj 2 =1 highlight the cell
```

Note: When other columns are included in the table use

```
Sum(Count(Name)Foreach(Addr.ID))ForAll(Column1;Column2)
```

I use foreach function to include the object in the calculation and forall to exclude the objects from the calculation

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I'm not able to test this as I'm not using BI any more since I've started working somewhere else. But I hope this will benefit others facing the same problem.